# Creating a transition on a :before or :after element

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using CSS3 transitions to make some fade in/out transitions on a link.

I've used the transition to make the background colour fade to nothing, but I'd like to make two "borders" fade in and also move down. The borders are not actually borders because I cannot use that to position it correctly, so I've used a psuedo element of a :before: with a 3px height to create a border effect.

My question is, is it possible to use CSS3 transitions (e.g fade in the colour or move the border down 3px)

```
li:hover:before{content: "";height: 3px;background-color: black;width: 100%;position: absolute;left: 0;top: -3px;}
li:hover:after{content: "";height: 3px;background-color: black;width: 100%;position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: -3px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akxrv4zf/1/

Comment: yes it is possible, but you haven't included any CSS for transitions in your example

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to style the `:after` and `:before` psuedo-elements WITHOUT the `:hover` psuedo event.

You need styles like: `li:before` AND styles like: `li:hover:before`.  Try something like below.

```css
/* Menu link animations */

li {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
  position: relative;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
li:before {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  transition: background 0.5s, top 0.5s;
}
li:after {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  transition: background 0.5s, bottom 0.5s;
}
li:hover:before {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -3px;
}
li:hover:after {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
}
/* General Link settings */

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 25px 2% 0 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #E7DAC6;
```

```html
<li>Example</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can style `:after` and `:before` elements just like any other element, including transitions.

Checkout this [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8vvmao66/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make give content to the `:after`,`:before` elements, so you can animate from one state to another.

If they do not have content from the start they are treated as `display:none` and you cannot apply transitions to elements whose state starts from `display:none`

```
li:before, li:after {
    content:"";
    height: 3px;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
}
li:before {top: 0px;}
li:after {bottom: 0px;}

li:hover:before {top: -3px;}
li:hover:after {bottom: -3px;}
li:hover:after, li:hover:before {
    background-color:black;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vmL8qt6k/1